# fileDownload primefaces does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download

I am trying to download a pdf file on my page:

```
                <p:commandButton action="#{patientCardMB.saveHistoryPdf()}" value="PDF" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-document" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)">
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{patientCardMB.file}" />  
                </p:commandButton>
```

Save history method:

```
public String saveHistoryPdf() throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<PatientCard> patientHistory = (ArrayList) getHistory();
    if (new HistoryPdf().createPdf(patientHistory)) {
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Project\\pdf\\" + patientHistory.get(0).getPatientId().getFirstName() + patientHistory.get(0).getPatientId().getLastName() + ".pdf");
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", "dsadsaa.pdf");
        sendInfoMessageToUser("Pdf został stworzony");
    } else {
        sendErrorMessageToUser("Podczas tworzenia pliku pdf wystąpił błąd");
    }
    return "pdf";
}
```

But the file download does not work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Errors in server (logfiles) /client (firebug, console) side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your action method from `p:commandButton` needs to be called earlier because the `StreamedContent` is not prepared yet. You could either do it in some kind of `init` method, use an `actionListener` instead of `action` or you could rewrite the `saveHistoryPdf` method like this:

```
public StreamedContent saveHistoryPdf() throws FileNotFoundException {
  ArrayList<PatientCard> patientHistory = (ArrayList) getHistory();
  if (new HistoryPdf().createPdf(patientHistory)) {
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Project\\pdf\\" + patientHistory.get(0).getPatientId().getFirstName() + patientHistory.get(0).getPatientId().getLastName() + ".pdf");
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", "dsadsaa.pdf");
    sendInfoMessageToUser("Pdf został stworzony");
  } else {
    sendErrorMessageToUser("Podczas tworzenia pliku pdf wystąpił błąd");
  }

  return file;
}
```

and therefore change the xhtml code to:

```
<p:commandButton value="PDF" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-document" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)">
  <p:fileDownload value="#{patientCardMB.saveHistoryPdf}" />  
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I had the same problem and I just forgot the "ajax='false'" ... Hope that will help the people with the same issue :)

Comment: They key is, in primefaces showcase uses FacesContext... but in differents enviroments you need to use FileInputStream.